# Why UnicodeEncodeError during **decoding**?

Tags: python, python-unicode

Why `UnicodeEncodeError` during **decoding**?

I estimated to get a `UnicodeDecodeError`.

```
>>> u'\udcc3'.decode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/foo_x_d/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\udcc3' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Because you already had Unicode.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know that it makes no sense to decode a unicode string. But what kind if **en**coding happens, if you try to decode a unicode string?

Comment: See the duplicate. The string is implicitly encoded as ASCII.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I looked at the other answer. I still don't understand why a unicode string needs to encoded with ascii first. But I don't want to dive into it deeper. Thank you very much for your (fast as light) answer. Have a nice day.

Comment: In Python 2, `unicode.decode()` exists to facilitate `unicode` -> `unicode` codecs such as `rot13`. The implementation was made too general (probably because mixing Unicode and byte strings has implicit encoding and decoding behaviour everywhere else in Python 2). This implicit behaviour caused way more pain than it solved issues, so Python 3 does away with that altogether.

Comment: @MartijnPieters good new, thank you. I hope to get Python 3 soon :-)

Comment: BTW, you may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.